# iOS recognize text and text separators

Tags: ios, tesseract, quartz-core, text-recognition

I am using Tesseract for text recognition.

How can I simply recognize padding between text and create e.g. pdf or .doc file with the same padding?

Let's say that the source page contains 3 columns with some text (like a news paper). How can I recognize this text with appropriate padding and margin to each other and to page?

Maybe you can suggest example or library that does the same or just algorithm?

Comment: Did you try to use tesseracts hOCR output?

Comment: @tobltobs no I will try it right now

Comment: @tobltobs the idea is to use char *boxtext = _tesseract->GetBoxText(0);?